# Woocommerce Product Bundles + Ajax Add to Cart + Continue Shopping on Add to Cart

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to achieve adding woocommerce product bundles to my cart via ajax, and then after the products are added, to have 2 buttons display. One for View Cart, and the other for Continue Shopping.

My searches are only turning up page reload to check the quantity on items in the cart in order to display those buttons.

As I am using ajax, I can't have the page reload to check if products are in the cart.

So, I need a solution that would keep me on the page.

Any Java help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with:

STEP 1: ADD THE CONTINUE SHOPPING BUTTON:
Plugin Editor > WooCommerce Product Bundles > Templates > Single Product > Add To Cart > bundle-add-to-cart-wrap.php
On line 80, close the php. Add this:

```
<a class="button wc-backward" id="continue-shopping" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>">Continue Shopping</a>
```

Reopen php

STEP 2: HIDE CONTINUE SHOPPING BUTTON ON PAGE LOAD:
Appearance > Customize > Additional CSS
Added:

```
#continue-shopping{
  display: none;
}
```

STEP 3: DISPLAY THE CONTINUE SHOPPING BUTTON ON PRODUCT ADD TO CART:
Plugin Editor > WooCommerce Product Bundles > Templates > Single Product > Add To Cart > bundle-button.php
Added

```
onclick="myFunction()"
```

To the button on line 21. So now it says:

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button bundle_add_to_cart_button button alt" onclick="myFunction()"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>
```

ALSO, ADD THE JAVASCRIPT:
Theme Editor > Child Theme > JS > ajax-add-to-cart.js
On bottom, add this:

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("continue-shopping").style.display = "block";
}
```